# I can't copy and paste from a console application

Tags: windows, console, visual-studio, copy-paste

I am usually working with console application and it is really annoying that I can not copy or paste anything on the console. How do I make it possible to copy & paste?

Answer (score 6):

- With QuickEdit mode turned **off**:

  - Right-click the console, select "Mark"
  - Select the area you want to copy
  - Right-click again

  To paste:

  - Right-click the console, select "Paste"
- With QuickEdit mode turned **on**:

  - Select text directly in the console
  - Right-click to copy

  To paste:

  - Right-click

If you're working frequently with console applications, you probably should make QuickEdit mode the default. Unless you're using something like Far that handles mouse input as well.

Comment: how to make it QuickEdit mode on ?

Comment: @Fresh: System menu → Properties

Comment: I don't think that this question is belongs to superuser because it is about Visual Studio so it can no be question of end users. Thank you very much it worked. But is there any other way in VS ? I remember that Netbeans ide was showing console output in IDE's window so it was more easy to coppy paste so possible to do that in VS ?

Comment: @Freshblood: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194436 ... there might be an add-in that makes this less painful, but this is probably as good as it gets in VS. As for whether the question belongs here or there ... well, if the question would have been »How can I show a console application's output in VS's output window?« then it would be SO material. In this case the question was not at all Visual Studio-related, therefore hardly programming. Also the Visual Studio context was only given in a tag and therefore less than obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about running a .NET application, switch off debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you need to use mouse for copy pasting on consol....that is the method that I follow!

On linux consol double click on word to copy the word and then press both mouse buttons at a time to paste it where the cursor is!!

Just use triple click to copy complete line!

Comment: Hidden in the tag is the mention of Visual Studio which points at **Windows** console.